# Android app to scan and fix SD card (no root)

Tags: android, diagnostics, flashcard, repair

Is there an app for Android which early diagnoses (bonus point: also fixes) any problems with flashcard storage media, especially damaged/undreadable files (similarly to CHKDSK.EXE)?

- Android 9 or higher
- scan the SD card with report of found problems
- no root access required

Bonus:

- ability to fix found issues
- scheduled periodic scan
- export of scan log or history of results
- exFAT support

Comment: I don't think there are any. Because to access every sector in the disk you really need root permissions, because otherwise you'll be able to read and write every file on the disk

Comment: Without root, there cannot be access to low-level things like "blocks"/"bad sectors". All such an app could do would be check the files – and how should it know whether some `.xkp` file has an issue if it doesn't know that file's format? So: what issues should that app check for? Not that I'd know any such app. If I should approach that on an Android device, first thought would be Termux with root powers, the required packages, and a script to call the corresponding tools.

Comment: @Izzy - I am searching for equivalent of CHKDSK.EXE.  Do your above comments mean that if manufacturer did not put such a tool into their Android distribution (e.g. imagine a hypothetical special tool in Samsung devices), Android users are helpless with fixing their SD card file system and the only thing they can do is to place their card into Windows PC and run CHKDSK.EXE there?

Comment: Oh, well, of course there is the `fsck` (FileSystemChecK) command-line tool. But you cannot access it directly without root. On windows you have the Administrator user, on Linux you have root – on Android you have … well, no full access. Ask the manufacturers for "why" (they're probably afraid of too many warranty requests from their customers who played with stuff they didn't understand).

Comment: chkdsk.exe does need admin rights. There are files on the disk that normal users are not allowed to access, therefore on any OS you do need full root permissions to read the raw sectors. Android also set permissions to folders on the SD card to limit apps to access only specific folders so without root you can't do anything

Comment: @Izzy – thank you. I wonder why Android/manufacturers do not ship a built-in user-accessible app to check the above... Built-in apps can perform system actions even on non-rooted device. But I was only wondering...

Comment: Nothing we can do about it. And you can try using `fsck` via a terminal (or `adb shell`) – it might be able to *scan,* but probably not to "fix stuff".

Answer (score 1):

don't worry there is simple solution, go to settings, device memory externel memmory card there is eject memory card option with eject icon, simplt press eject memory card icon, & your memory card safely unmounted, than click mount option, so your android os will check your sd card before mounting, & fix any ploblems if found, & move any corrupt files in folder named like .lost or lostfiles, Alway use orignel microSD cards that will come in atleast five year warrenty they are good & you will not found any problems or errors in there.